# Populational model with parameter

Tags: linear-algebra

In preparation of my math exam I was trying to solve some exercises about population models.

The question is as follows:

---

*Consider a population model with two species $X$ and $Y$. The populational growth of $X$ after $k$ years is indicated by $x_k$ and for $Y$ this is $y_k$. Let's assume that these populations evolve according to the following equations
$$
x_{k+1} = \frac{1}{4}(x_k + 2ay_k)
$$
$$and$$
$$
y_{k+1} = \frac{1}{8}(2y_k + ax_k)
$$
where $a>1$ is a constant.*

---

**(a)** Write these equations in matrix-vector form and calculate the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues of the occuring matrix (as functions of $a$).

**(b)** For what values of $a$ is the growth exponential? For what values does the population go extinct?

**(c)** For what value of $a$ is the population in equilibrum? Calculate the equilibrum population if $x_0=300$ and $y_0 = 100$.

---

Question a is relatively easy

Matrix-vector form is:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_{k+1}\\ y_{k+1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{4}&\frac{a}{2}\\ \frac{a}{8}&\frac{1}{4} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_{k}\\ y_{k} \end{pmatrix}$$

Eigenvalues are:$\frac{1}{4} \pm \frac{a}{4}$

Now I'm stuck with questions b and c. An explanation on how to solve these would be very much appreciated!

*(**P.S.** I translated this question from Dutch to English so excuse my 'rough' translation and/or spelling/vocabulary errors)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you a full answer but I'll give you the steps to get to it.

You've found the eigenvalues. Now find the eigenvectors then build a matrix $U$ made of those eigenvectors (say, as columns, that is, each column of $U$ is one of the eigenvectors).

Once you have this matrix $U$, you can uncouple the equations, that is, you will be able to define new population variables $x'$ and $y'$ such that the time-evolution of $x'$ depends only on $x'$ and the time-evolution of $y'$ depends only on $y'$. Hint: $x = Ux'$.

This will let you solve for the time-evolution of both $x'$ and $y'$ in terms of $a$ and $k$. How? By replacing $x$ and $y$ in the original matrix equation with $x = Ux'$ and $y = \ldots$. ($y$ is for you to figure out).

You can then go back to the original population variables $x$ and $y$, which will each be a linear superposition of both $x'$ and $y'$. How? Well, if $x = Ux'$ and you have $x'$, then...

Since you'll have solved for the time-evolution of $x'$ and $y'$, you'll have a complete solution to both $x$ and $y$. Then it's a matter of looking at what happens to them for various values of $a$, as $k$ increases.